# Compile Flex 4 theme in Flash Builder 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, themes

How to compile Flex theme SWC from `file.css` and additional skin classes in Flash Builder 4?

I've tried creating simple **Flex Library project** but it does not seem to use CSS file because resulting SWC does not work as theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has started working after adding `defaults.css` to the library assets and `mx|Button` class declaration. Seems like a bug for me.